# sed or perl replace characters leaving some text intact

Tags: perl, replace, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sed replace characters leaving some text intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490806/sed-replace-characters-leaving-some-text-intact)

how to replace some characters using sed (or maybe perl), but leaving unknown number intact in.e. in file there are multiple lines like this:

```
<"START=xxx">
<"START=yyy">
<"START=zzz">
```

The 'xxx', 'yyy' and 'zzz' are different unknown values (numbers). I want to remove ending "> and replace it, also replace the beginning (but that's not to difficult for me) so in the end the file looks like this:

```
<START>xxx</START>
<START>yyy</START>
<START>zzz</START>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: new user tip: Do you think someone asked it before? :-)

Comment: have you tried the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490806/sed-replace-characters-leaving-some-text-intact

Comment: @Fredrik ha :) probably did not know how to edit the question. _edit_: if you look at the comments, seems not to be the case :/ dunno .. I voted for exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
sed 's;<"\([^=]\+\)=\([^"]\+\)">;<\1>\2</\1>;' file
```

however keep in mind that processing `xml` like content with line-oriented tools is not the correct way to do it, unless the format is very strict and the case focuses on a strict and well-defined subset of the formatting language.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, a Perl solution:

```
perl -pe's#<"(.+?)=(\d+)">#<$1>$2</$1>#' <file >outfile
```

or

```
perl -pie's#<"(.+?)=(\d+)">#<$1>$2</$1>#' file
```

for in-place replacement

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"=" '{gsub(/\"|<|>/,"");print "<"$1">"$2"</"$1">"}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
<"START=xxx">
<"START=yyy">
<"START=zzz">
> awk -F"=" '{gsub(/\"|<|>/,"");print "<"$1">"$2"</"$1">"}' temp
<START>xxx</START>
<START>yyy</START>
<START>zzz</START>
```